# Check if MacOS version is Greater Than or Equal to

Tags: r

After assessing that a user is using Darwin, how can I us R to check if they have >= version?  For example I'm running Sonoma which is version 23.0.0.  In the code below we see the system call says 23.0.0.

```
> system("uname -r")
23.0.0
```

How can I then compare this output to a value?  I'd expect the following to be TRUE.

```
> system("uname -r") >= '23.0.0'
23.0.0
[1] FALSE
```

This also gave a FALSE:

```
> as.numeric_version(system("uname -r")) >= '23.0.0'
23.0.0
[1] FALSE
```

And tried:

```
> as.numeric(capture.output(system("uname -r"))) >= '23.0.0'
23.0.0
logical(0)
```

```
> as.numeric_version(capture.output(system("uname -r"))) >= '23.0.0'
23.0.0
logical(0)
```

Comment: What's the result of saving off `x <- system("uname -r")` then `dput(x)`? Total stab in the dark, but do you need to `capture.output` this text?

Comment: @thelatemail It gives `0L`.  I tried and it gives logical(0)

Comment: What about `system("uname -r", intern=TRUE)`? - *intern: a logical (not 'NA') which indicates whether to capture the output of the command as an R character vector.*

Comment: @thelatemail that's it.  Can you add as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

According to the `?system` help file, you need to explicitly request that R captures the output of the command as something usable to R:

```
system("uname -r", intern=TRUE)
```

> intern: a logical (not 'NA') which indicates whether to capture the
> output of the command as an R character vector.

Comment: I should have mentioned...I took your answer and wrapped with `as.numeric_version` but like @Mikael Jagan's answer even better.

Answer (score 3):

@thelatemail's comment about `intern=TRUE` is good and will work much of the time, but I think you need a little more to do valid package comparisons (e.g. when version number components have different numbers of digits).

On my system, the results of `uname -r` have some alphabetic stuff that I have to trim to make the results a valid R version type:

```r
s <- system("uname -r", intern = TRUE) |>
   gsub(pattern = "-[[:alpha:]]*", replacement = "")
# [1] "6.4.676060406"
```

(could also have used `stringr::str_remove()`)

Comparing with "6.4.6761", which is *numerically* less than the last package component:

```r
s < "6.4.6761"  ## TRUE
as.package_version(s) < "6.4.6761" ## FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just use `Sys.info` ... ?

```r
> info <- Sys.info()
> str(info)
 Named chr [1:8] "Darwin" "22.6.0" ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8] "sysname" "release" "version" "nodename" ...
> info[["sysname"]]
[1] "Darwin"
> info[["release"]]
[1] "22.6.0"
> as.numeric_version(info[["release"]]) >= "23.0.0"
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Do you know offhand what the difference is between `as.numeric_version()` and `as.package_version()` ? `as.package_version()` eventually calls `.make_numeric_version`, ... while `as.numeric_version()` does something a little bit simpler ...

Comment: They both eventually call `.make_numeric_version`, but they pass different values for argument `regexp` to reflect the fact that R package versions are numeric versions with at least two components (and accordingly `package_version` is an S3 subclass of `numeric_version`).